# omit by or present participle

Tags: grammar

He disagrees death penalty "arguing" that it does not deter crime.

I don't know if "arguing" is present participle of penalty or if it from omitting disagree (by) arguing that.

Comment: That sentence is not grammatical.  Please cite the source, and please double check that you have written everything correctly.

Comment: I downvoted the question because it lacked detail, and you do not say where the quotation comes from. Please edit and improve the post. And please use another tag beside grammar, alone it is meaningless. Every question on ELL could be tagged "grammar".

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence is not good English.

One obvious way to express the same thought grammatically is

"He disagrees with the death penalty by arguing that it does not deter crime."

EDIT: Based on the comment by the OP below, my answer must be expanded. The answer being looked for by the examiners is that "by" was omitted. "Arguing" is not modifying penalty. It still remains that the sentence provided is not good English.

Comment: Thanks. This is one of the questions in my entrance exam though. :[

Comment: @Kiw I have expanded my answer in response to your comment.